# Nullable datetime value from DatePicker

Tags: c#, nullable

This is the case. I get the date from DatePicker control:

DateTime current = datePicker1.SelectedDate;

And I get an error: Cannot implicitly convert DateTime? to DateTime. So I guess it's up to a nullable type DateTime?.

Is it safe to cast this type to a type I need like this:

```
if (datePicker1.SelectedDate == null)
    current= DateTime.Now;
else
    current= (DateTime)datePicker1.SelectedDate; //or datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value
```

And in general, when is it SAFE to implicitly cast nullable values, and when it isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nullable types have a special property for this kind of thinks. It is HasValue, and moreover GetValueOrDefault. So what You really need is

```
DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
```

`// or DateTime.MaxValue or whatever)`.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
current = datePicker1.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

That will use `SelectedDate` if it's non-null, or `DateTime.Now` otherwise. The type of the expression is non-nullable, because the last operand is.

In general, you should use the `Value` property (or cast to the non-nullable type) if you're confident that the value is non-null at that point - so that if it *is* null, it will throw an exception. (If you're confidence is misplaced, an exception is appropriate.) Quite often the null coalescing operator means you don't need to worry about this though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast, the following

```
if (datePicker1.SelectedDate == null)
   current= DateTime.Now; 
else 
   current= datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
```

should do

Comment: according to MSND, datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value is the same as (DateTime)datePicker1.SelectedDate. Both belong to a explicit conversions

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DateTime current = datePicker1.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

?